# What is the best way to use Gtalk on iphone?

Tags: iphone, chat

What is the best way to use Gtalk on iphone?

Comment: There IS a lot apps to access gtalk. BUT, the best app for that is no doubt the BeejiveIM app.

Answer (score 3):

Since Google does a pretty good job of making their websites mobile-friendly, navigating to http://talkgadget.google.com/ and logging in should present you with a nice chatting interface.

On the iOS app side, [imo](https://imo.im/) seems to be a popular choice, though I can't personally vouch for it (the mobile web interface works fine for me when I'm away from a real computer)

Answer (score 0):

For an app that can not only handle the IM features of Gtalk, but also the voice features, check out [Talkatone](http://www.talkatone.com).

Otherwise, there's [too many iOS apps to list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11799/what-is-the-best-chat-client-app-for-ipod-touch) that can interface with Gtalk via their XMPP protocol, as well as accessing [Google's web app](http://www.google.com/talk) via Mobile Safari.

Comment: I think the talkone is like viber

Comment: AFAIK Viber does not interface with Google Talk or Google Voice.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use an app called eBuddy http://www.ebuddy.com/ that I use for a Gtalk chat client. It also lets you use other chat clients like AIM and msn. There are many different apps out there that I am sure do the same thing but I really like eBuddy.

Comment: dear lord ebuddy is evil! http://www.sfgate.com/cgi-bin/blogs/ybenjamin/detail?entry_id=46417  search for ebuddy